# Как в питоне сгенерировать все возможные строки, соответствующие регулярному выражению?

Tags: python, регулярные-выражения

Есть некое регулярное выражение, например, "[a-z][0-9]{3}|[a-z]{3}". Как получить список всех возможных строк, соответствующих этому выражению? Примерно такой:

```
['a781', 'b000', 'c476', 'u132', 'd997', 'exe', 'use' и т.д.]
```

Comment: Есть такие регулярные выражения, которым может соответствовать бесконечное число строк. Поэтому написать вариант на все случаи жизни вряд ли получится. И, соответственно, стандартных решений нет.

Comment: Поддерживаю вышевысказавшегося) если есть конкретная регулярка, то пишите, поможем написать скрипт, генерирующий список.

Comment: @skegg s/список/итератор/. Устроит?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Кроме самых простых случаев (без `*+`), кол-во строк, соотвествующих заданному регулярному выражению, может быть бесконечно.

Обратить регулярное выражение достаточно легко, например, `re` модуль позволяет получить регулярное выражение в виде дерева, обходя которое можно [cгенерировать подходящую строку](https://stackoverflow.com/a/502074/4279):

```
import re
from pprint import pprint

regex = "[a-z][0-9]{3}|[a-z]{3}"
pprint(re.sre_parse.parse(regex).data)
```

Результат:

```
[('branch',
  (None,
   [[('in', [('range', (97, 122))]), ('max_repeat', (3, 3, [('in', [('range', (48, 57))])]))],
    [('max_repeat', (3, 3, [('in', [('range', (97, 122))])]))]]))]
```

[bjmc написал `rstr.xeger` функцию](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9118086/4279), которая возвращает (одну, любую) строку, удовлетворяющую заданному regex:

```
import rstr # $ pip install rstr

regex = "[a-z][0-9]{3}|[a-z]{3}"
print(rstr.xeger(regex)) # print a single string that matches the regex
# -> ycu
```

[Paul McGuire (pyparsing) упомянул](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5006339/4279) 
сайт [Инвертер регулярных выражений](http://utilitymill.com/utility/Regex_inverter), основанный на [invRegex.py](http://pyparsing.wikispaces.com/file/view/invRegex.py) примере:

```
from itertools import islice
from invRegex import invert # http://pyparsing.wikispaces.com/file/view/invRegex.py

regex = "[a-z][0-9]{3}|[a-z]{3}"
print("\n".join(islice(invert(regex), 10000))) # print < 10000 matching strings
```

Результат:

```
a000
a001
a002
a003
a004
a005
a006
a007
a008
a009
a010
a011
a012
a013
a014
a015
a016
a017
a018
a019
a020
a021
a022
a023
a024
...
```

Примеры взяты из ответов к [Reversing a regular expression in python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/492716/4279).

Comment: Плюсег за `re.sre_parse.parse(regex).data`

Answer (score 3):

Для начала нужно проанализировать выражение с целью выявления, можно ли вообще перебрать все варианты для него. Потом уже составить варианты перебора. Потом посмотреть на замечательный модуль [itertools](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html) и, собственно, перебрать все нужные варианты.

Для указанного регулярного выражения это будет выглядеть примерно вот так:

```
from string import digits, ascii_lowercase
from itertools import product

# [a-z][0-9]{3}
l1 = list( product(ascii_lowercase, digits, digits, digits) )

# [a-z]{3}
l2 = list( product(ascii_lowercase, ascii_lowercase, ascii_lowercase ) )

# concatenate
l = l1 + l2

# and join inner lists
res = [''.join(i) for i in l]
```