# Получить текст между скобок с вложением

Tags: регулярные-выражения, python-3.x

Приветствую! Есть фразы примерно такого вида:

```
shingle1 = 'уснуть (навеки|(могильным|вечным) сном)'
shingle2 = 'отдать (богу душу|концы)'
shingle3 = '(дать|врезать) (дубаря|дуба)'
```

Необходимо преобразовать строки таким образом:

```
shingle1_r = 'уснуть навеки|уснуть могильным сном|уснуть вечным сном)'
shingle2_r = 'отдать богу душу|отдать концы'
shingle3_r = 'дать дубаря|дать дуба|врезать дубаря|врезать дуба'
```

Причем может быть несколько вложенных пар скобок. Видимо нужно получить текст из "самых внешних" скобок, затем проверить, есть ли скобки внутри и т.д., по пути сохраняя фрагменты текста...

Прошу вас оказать помощь! Благодарю за внимание.

Comment: С какой проблемой вы столкнулись?

Comment: Более общая задача (сгенерировать все строки соответствующие регулярному выражению): https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/395865/23044

Comment: Пробовал через рег. выражения получить текст в скобках, но получается так: "навеки|(могильным|вечным". Т.е. как только встречает первую ")", на этом все заканчивается. `re.compile(r'\((.*?)\)')`