# Как извлечь списки из строки? Получить случайный вариант по шаблону '...{a|b|c}...{d|e}'

Tags: python, python-3.x

Как в Python можно получить списки из указанной строки, если количество списков заранее не известно?

Есть код:

```
text = 'Привет! Мы {развлекаемся|отрываемся|веселимся}, а {ты|вы}?'
```

В итоге хотелось бы получать каждый раз случайные варианты, вроде:

> print(text) # Привет! Мы отрываемся, а ты?

или:

> print(text) # Привет! Мы развлекаемся, а вы?

Comment: А где здесь словари? Тут списки, на сколько я вижу.

Comment: @Sergey Gornostaev Уточнил вопрос

Comment: связанный вопрос [Как в питоне сгенерировать все возможные строки, соответствующие регулярному выражению?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/395865/23044)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import random
import re

text = 'Привет! Мы {развлекаемся|отрываемся|веселимся}, а {ты|вы}?'

text1 = ''.join(item if not item.startswith('{')
                     else random.choice(item.strip('{}').split('|'))
                for item in re.split(r'({.*?})', text))

print(text1)
# Привет! Мы отрываемся, а вы?
```

Что тут происходит?

Во-первых, разбиваем текст на части регулярным выражением:

```
print(re.split(r'({.*?})', text))
# ['Привет! Мы ', '{развлекаемся|отрываемся|веселимся}', ', а ', '{ты|вы}', '?']
```

Проверяем каждый элемент, начинается ли он с фигурной скобки. Если нет - сразу возвращаем сам элемент, если начинается, убираем скобки, разбиваем на части, возвращаем случайно выбранную часть (пример для того, чтобы видеть, что происходит с каждой частью):

```
for item in re.split(r'({.*?})', text):
    print(item if not item.startswith('{') else random.choice(item.strip('{}').split('|')))

# Привет! Мы 
# развлекаемся
# , а 
# вы
# ?
```

Ну а дальше все части собираем в цельную строку с помощью `join`, см. полный пример в начале ответа.

Answer (score 3):

Можно использовать синтаксис регулярных выражений, а затем сгенерировать случайную строку, которая этому regex соответствует. К примеру, используя [`rstr` модуль](https://bitbucket.org/leapfrogdevelopment/rstr/):

```
>>> import rstr  # $ pip install rstr
>>> regex = r'Привет! Мы (развлекаемся|отрываемся|веселимся), а (ты|вы)\?'
>>> rstr.xeger(regex)
'Привет! Мы развлекаемся, а вы?'
>>> rstr.xeger(regex)
'Привет! Мы веселимся, а ты?'
```

Есть и другие варианты, см: [Как в питоне сгенерировать все возможные строки, соответствующие регулярному выражению?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/395865/23044)

Comment: Вариант отличный и наиболее простой. Но в моем случае не совсем подходит, так как основная строка текста в другом формате. Благодарю.

Comment: @Владимир вы в вопросе явно упомянули что формат можно менять или это не так?

Comment: да, прошу прощения. Исправил. Имелось ввиду то, что если указанным образом никак нельзя будет осуществить задуманное, то я бы присмотрелся к другим вариантам. Но вот предложили выше конкретное решение. Я его и выбрал, так как оно мне более подходит.

Comment: @Владимир теперь это делает мой ответ неверным. Такие изменения не стоит вносить в вопрос, которые существующие ответы делают неверными. Ответы на Stack Overflow не только для автора, но и для будущих читателей с похожей проблемой (95% траффика из поисковиков)—это тонкое отличие от обычных форумов. Ответ, который лично вам помог, вы совершенно правильно отметили "принятым".

Answer (score 2):

```
from random import choice

a = ['развлекаемся', 'отрываемся', 'веселимся']
b = ['ты', 'вы']

text = 'Привет! Мы {}, а {}?'.format(choice(a), choice(b))
```

Comment: Немного не подходит этот вариант в том плане, что заранее не известно, сколько будет списков. Но все равно благодарю за вариант.

Answer (score 0):

Попробовал сам набросать следующий код:

```
text_message = 'Hi! I play {guitar|the accordion|violin}, and {he|she} or {one|two|tree}?'

def getRandomChoice(text):


 label_one = text.find('{')
 label_two = text.find('}')

 if label_one != -1:
    list_one = text[label_one + 1:label_two].split('|')
    text = text[:label_one] + choice(list_one) + text[label_two + 1:]

    label_tree = text.find('{')
    label_four = text.find('}')

    if label_tree != -1:
        list_two = text[label_tree + 1:label_four].split('|')
        text = text[:label_tree] + choice(list_two) + text[label_four + 1:]

        label_five = text.find('{')
        label_six = text.find('}')

        if label_five != -1:
            list_tree = text[label_five + 1:label_six].split('|')
            text = text[:label_five] + choice(list_tree) + text[label_six + 1:]

 return text


print(getRandomChoice(text_message))
```

Пока не придумал ничего лучше. Поддерживает до трех списков. Если у кого-то есть еще варианты - предлагайте.