# Выбор и замена текста в файле

Tags: python, python-3.x, текст

В файле text.txt содержится текст:

```
Привет, (Дима,Вася,Игорь)! (Как дела?,Как настроение?,Как жизнь?)
Пойдешь (завтра,сегодня,на следующей неделе) на тренировку?
```

Задача: создать функцию, которая принимает этот текст и возвращает его обратно, но при этом выбирать только одно значение из скобок и заменять им скобки. Выбор случайный. С учетом переносов строк. Количество скобок не известно. Например:

```
Привет, Вася! Как дела?
Пойдешь сегодня на тренировку?
```

Подскажите, как это реализовать?
Пока ничего лучше не придумал, как это:

```
def random_text( text ):
    while True:
        label_find1 = text.find('(')
        label_find2 = text.find(')')
        if label_find1 == -1:
            break

        tmp_text1 = text[label_find1:label_find2 + 1]
        tmp_text2 = text[label_find1 + 1:label_find2]
        tmp_list = tmp_text2.split(',')
        tmp_var = random.choice(tmp_list)
        text = text.replace(tmp_text1, tmp_var)


return text
```

Comment: Подскажите плз, где задачку брали?

Comment: Нигде, просто возникла необходимость в этом при работе.

Comment: Связанный вопрос: [Как извлечь списки из строки? Получить случайный вариант по шаблону '…{a|b|c}…{d|e}'](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/816971/1365)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вариант через регулярку с [re.sub](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.sub):

```
import re
import random


def random_text(text: str) -> str:
    def _on_sub_process(match) -> str:
        # "Дима,Вася,Игорь" -> ["Дима", "Вася", "Игорь"]
        variants = match.group(1).split(',')
        return random.choice(variants)

    # В регулярке выполняется замена выражений внутри круглых скобок
    return re.sub(r'\((.+?)\)', _on_sub_process, text)


text = "Привет, (Дима,Вася,Игорь)! (Как дела?,Как настроение?,Как жизнь?) Пойдешь (завтра,сегодня,на следующей неделе) на тренировку?"
new_text = random_text(text)
print(new_text)  # Привет, Игорь! Как настроение? Пойдешь сегодня на тренировку?

new_text = random_text(text)
print(new_text)  # Привет, Дима! Как жизнь? Пойдешь сегодня на тренировку?
```