# произвести замену в шаблоне по условию

Tags: python, python-3.x, format

Нужно сформатировать строку (желательно методом format). Строка, например, такая:

```
string = "words{hello||hello1}words"
```

А до этой строки задается параметр `s=True` или `s=False`, и если `s=True`, то на выходе должна получиться вот что:

```
string = 'wordshellowords'
```

, а если `s=False`, то:

```
string = 'wordshello1words'
```

Как это сделать?

Comment: я так понимаю вы берете текст из файла,либо он уже в коде,но пользователь его не вводит?

Comment: Связанные вопросы: [Выбор и замена текста в файле](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/890934/Выбор-и-замена-текста-в-файле), [Как извлечь списки из строки? Получить случайный вариант по шаблону '…{a|b|c}…{d|e}'](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/816971/Как-извлечь-списки-из-строки-Получить-случайный-вариант-по-шаблону-abc)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Алгоритм по шагам:

```
string = "words{hello||hello1}words"

start = string.index('{') + 1
end = string.index('}')

replace_str = string[start: end]
print(replace_str)  # hello||hello1

var_replace = replace_str.split('||')
print(var_replace)  # ['hello', 'hello1']

string = string.replace(replace_str, '')
print(string)  # words{}words

s = True
if s:
    new_string = string.format(var_replace[0])
    print(new_string)  # wordshellowords
else:
    new_string = string.format(var_replace[1])
    print(new_string)  # wordshello1words
```

#### В виде функции:

```
def foo(string: str, s=True) -> str:
    start, end = string.index('{') + 1, string.index('}')

    replace_str = string[start: end]
    var_replace = replace_str.split('||')
    string = string.replace(replace_str, '')
    
    # Можно схитрить, т.к. True -- 1, False -- 0
    # return string.format(var_replace[not s])
    return string.format(var_replace[0] if s else var_replace[1])


string = "words{hello||hello1}words"
print(foo(string, True))   # wordshellowords
print(foo(string, False))  # wordshello1words
```

#### Вариант через регулярку:

```
import re

def foo(string: str, s=True) -> str:
    def _on_match(match):
        var_replace = match.group()[1:-1].split('||')
        return var_replace[0] if s else var_replace[1]

    return re.sub('{.+?}', _on_match, string)


string = "words{hello||hello1}words"
print(foo(string, True))   # wordshellowords
print(foo(string, False))  # wordshello1words
```

Comment: А нельзя ли сделать, чтобы там было несколько {hello||hello1}???
P.S. Получаетс только с одним(((

Comment: @Иван, можно, но это изменение задачи, и кода :) Могу подсказать быстрое решение для регулярки: изменить ее на `'{.+?}'`, тогда, обработка будет ленивой (не жадной) и для `string = "words{hello||hello1}words_{hello||hello1}_"` получите: `wordshello1words_hello1_`

Answer (score 4):

Чтобы выбрать при замене в шаблоне первую альтернативу, когда `first=True`:

```
import re

format_spec = "words{AAA||BBB}words"
first = True
print(re.sub(
    "{([^}]+)}", 
    lambda match: match.group(1).split("||")[not first],
    format_spec,
))
```

Результат:

```
wordsAAAwords
```

Здесь используется, что `True == 1`, а `False == 0`, поэтому булевы переменные могут использоваться в качестве индексов. К примеру, `[1, 2][True]` возвращает `2`, а `[1, 2][False]` возвращает `1`.

Answer (score 3):

```python
string = 'words{}words'
subs = ['hello1', 'hello']

s = True

print(string.format(subs[s]))  # wordshellowords
```

Трюк в том, что при преобразовании в целое число `True` станет `1`, а `False` – `0`, и таким образом выбираем элемент по индексу.

Comment: Более того, `False == 0`, `True == 1`

Answer (score 2):

```
import re
string = 'words{hello||hello1}words'
parts = re.split(r'[{|}]', string)

if s == True:
    print(parts[0] + parts[1] + parts[-1])
else:
    print(parts[0] + parts[-2] + parts[-1])
```

Answer (score 2):

```
string = "wordshello{}words"

s = True
print(string.format(int(s) or ''))  # 'wordshello1words'

s = False
print(string.format(int(s) or ''))  # 'wordshellowords'
```